# gettimeofday behavior on windows C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to find a number in a vector of  10000000 numbers, which is a very big vector I guess. But the problem is I am getting

> time taken by linear search equal to 0 ms

when i search any number in the vector. What I expect is it should be in order of milliseconds or secconds though it is a big vector.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;


void search(vector<int>& num , int key)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
    {
        if(num[i] == key)
        {
            cout << "Found"  << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> num;

    for(int i= 0; i < 100000; i++)
        num.push_back(i);

    cout << "Enter the key : " ;
    int key;
    cin >> key;

    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Time;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds ms;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<float> fsec;
    auto t0 = Time::now();

    //struct timeval t1, t2;
    //gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    search(num , key);
    //gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    //double timeDiff = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec)*1000.0 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec)/1000.0;
    //cout << "Time taken for linear search " << timeDiff << " ms" << endl;
    auto t1 = Time::now();
    fsec fs = t1 - t0;
    ms d = std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(fs);
    std::cout << fs.count() << "s\n";
    std::cout << d.count() << "ms\n";


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You probably should use `std::chrono`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now

Comment: Not working , getting 0 seconds and 0 milliseconds again.

Comment: The default minimum time increment offered up by Windows varies from version to version and can be modified by system calls. It used to be 1/64 of a second, around 15 ms, but I don't do enough high-precision timing in Windows to know the default in is these days. I wouldn't expect better than 1 ms though, and a multi- GHz computer can blow through 10 million `vector` elements pretty darn fast.

Comment: Did you compile your code with any optimization flags ? Put your code here https://godbolt.org/  and compile with -O3 (gcc), you will see that `search` function is never called. Add bool as return value from search, and count how many keys were found, then print this value, in this case `search` must be called and you can measure time.

Comment: I didn't use any optimisation flags and my function gets called , i.e why I am getting "Found" as cout.

Answer (score 3):

Look at disassembled your program. The function `search` returns nothing, changes nothing, therefore the compiler decided to remove evaluation, thus the loop at all. The function body became empty and its call was removed.

Comment: The function call didn't become empty as I am getting "Found" as cout when I entered 99999 as key in the above program.

Comment: Do not deceive me and others . You have updated your original question.

Comment: Yes after your comment , I added the cout to verify.

Comment: And you decreased the vector size. 100 thousand is a small size.

Comment: I added the cout after your comment to verify whether the function is being called or not ?

Comment: So you are saying in a vector of 100 thousand, linear search won't take even 1 milliseocond ?

Comment: The timer precision is about 10-20 ms.

Comment: Is there any other more accurate way

Comment: Return 10 million elements.

Comment: Find out  and possibly change the timer tick. Run your experiment a few thousand times and compute the average.